# binary search tree diagram for numbers 1 to 10

Tags: sorting, binary-search-tree

How would i draw a binary search diagram for numbers 1 to 10?
Would it be split into two sub-trees or would it be 1 straight line with the nodes to the right of the parent node?
The diagram is to start with 1 as the parent node.

Answer (score 1):

The value in the middle should be the root, this is to get the lowest height in your tree.
Then from there just write two pointers on each node one for the lower and one for the greater and so on, until you get to your leafs nodes.

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

```
             5
       3          8
    2    4     7        9
  1          6              10
```